# Creating a bibliographic entry for, and referencing a report from a Governmental Commission

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I want to reference a report by The Financial Crisis Comission. For that, I've used the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{Bibliography/Bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

some loooooooooooooong text\footnote{ See \textcite{FCIC11} }

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

In the Bibliography.bib file I have

```
@report{FCIC11,
    author      = {The Financial Crisis Inquiry Comission},
    title       = {The Financial Crisis Inquiry Report - Final Report of the National Comission on the Causes of the Financial and
Economic Crisis in the United States},
    institution = {US Government Printing Office},
    year        = {2011}
}
```

However, in the text, what is shown is `Comission(2011)`, as if `The Financial Crisis Inquiry Comission` was the name of a person.

How can I reference it as `The Financial Crisis Inquiry Comission (2011)`

Comment: A possible work-around that popped in my mind: use double braces, i.e. {{The Financial Crisis Inquiry Comission}}

Comment: @Bart thanks, it seems to work. ;)